# Размер стрелок vectors gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Как можно увеличить размер стрелок при построении векторного поля в gnuplot? Я использую

```
set style arrow 1 size 3
```

Но у меня увеличивается длина стрелки, а мне нужно чтобы увеличивался сам кончик стрелки, указывающий направление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень странно, что Ваш стиль увеличивает длину стрелки. Параметр `size` задает длины каждой из веток стрелки (крылья), а не просто ее длину. И в Вашем случае никакой стрелки нет вообще - она будет изображена в виде простой черточки (я использовал gnuplot 5.2.8, но думаю, это не принципиально), так как Вы не указали с стиле параметр `head`. Длина же этой черточки задается как параметры `dx`,`dy` в команде `plot`. Кроме длины ветвей стрелки еще хорошо бы задавать угол расхождения ветвей от оси: вот комбинация этих параметров (`size` и `angle`) и будет давать в итоге длину стрелки. Ну и для пущей красоты, еще имеет смысл задавать параметры `backangle` (угол раствора задней линии стрелок) и `fill`, чтобы сделать заливку между передней и задней линией у стрелки. Вместо `fill`. можно еще использовать параметр `noborder` - с ним будет видна только та часть стрелки, которая была "залита", а сами линии видны не будут (так стрелка будет чуть меньшего размера). Последний параметр рекомендуют использовать также когда для отрисовки "черточки" используется не сплошная линия, а с каким-то стилем, типа пунктира.

А теперь можно переходить к примерам. В скрипте я определяю несколько стилей стрелок.

```
reset

set style arrow 1 head size 0.5,3,25 filled lc rgbcolor "blue" lw 2
set style arrow 2 head size screen 0.1,3,25  noborder lc rgbcolor "blue" lw 2
set style arrow 3 head size 0.15, 10,60 fixed filled lc rgbcolor "green"
set style arrow 4 size 3

# следующие два параметра задают общее количество вычисляемых точек для графика
set samples 10
set isosamples 10,10

set xrange [-pi:pi]
set yrange [-pi:pi]

# это даст стрелки различной длины
#dx(x) = sin(x/2.0)
#dy(x) = cos(x)

# это даст стрелки одинаковой длины
dx(x) = 0.2 * sgn(sin(x))
dy(x) = 0.2 * sgn(cos(x))

plot "++" using 1:2:(dx($1)):(dy($2)) w vec arrowstyle 1 title 'Направление какого-то поля'
```

**Стиль 1** в моем примере задает стрелку (с параметром `head`) с заливкой, с длиной крыльев 0.5 (по умолчанию, если верить документации, используется координатная система, совпадающая с осью `x`, но координатную систему можно указать явно, как я сделал для стиля 2). Кроме длин крыльев стрелки я также задаю угол отклонения передней и задней линий, которые и формируют саму стрелку. Ну и еще применяю заливку. Также здесь видно, что к стрелке можно применять стандартные средства для управления стилем линий (задаю цвет и толщину линий).

**Стиль 2** отличается тем, что я для указания длин крыльев стрелки использую "экранные координаты", а вместо ключевого слова `fill` для заливки использую `noborder`, чтобы не рисовались окаймляющие линии стрелки. При этом, хоть мы и не рисуем сами линии, параметр `lw` задающий толщину линии, все-равно влияет на внешний вид.

**Стиль 3** после блока с размерами (`size ...`) использует ключевое слово `fixed`. Насколько я понял, оно заставляет gnuplot рисовать все стрелки (в смысле, именно ту часть с "крыльями") одного размера (вне зависимости от величин `dx`,`dy`), а не пропорционально величинам `dx`,`dy`.

В примере я сделал фиксированными по величине значения для `dx`,`dy` для наглядности. Можно заккоментировать эти функции и расскоментировать их версии с переменной длиной, тогда будет видно, чем отличается стиль 3 от остальных.

**Стиль 4** - это Ваш стиль из вопроса, чтобы можно было и его увидеть.

Ниже привожу график с использованным стилем 1.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:** *Можно стиль отрисовки границы выбрать отличным от стиля заливки самой стрелки? То есть, например, я хочу отрисовать стрелку одним цветом, а залить направляющий кончик другим?*

Прямого способа так сделать я не нашел, но можно сделать что-то похожее.
Я приведу только измененные (добавленные) строки к уже имеющемуся примеру выше. Можно сделать два стиля стрелок - один "с пустыми" стрелками, второй, точно такой же, но сделать его без линий (через `noborder`). А потом просто рисовать два графика, один поверх другого, с одними и теми же параметрами, только использовать эти стили по-очереди:

```
set style arrow 5 head size 0.7,3,25 empty lc rgbcolor "blue" lw 2 
set style arrow 6 head size 0.7,3,25 noborder lc rgbcolor "red" lw 2 

plot "++" using 1:2:(dx($1)):(dy($2)) w vec arrowstyle 5 title 'Направление какого-то поля',\
"++" using 1:2:(dx($1)):(dy($2)) w vec arrowstyle 6 notitle
```

У этого способа есть один недостаток: я не знаю, можно ли сформировать такую же стрелку в легенде (скорее всего, нет). То есть, при таком способе рисования лучше будет легенду убрать совсем (я в примере оставил легенду для "пустых" стрелок, а с заливкой - убрал).

В итоге получается вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Естественно, внешний вид можно немного изменить, если поменять порядок отрисовки этих графиков, но тогда толщину линий (параметр `lw`) лучше уменьшить хотя бы до 1.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Владимир!

Comment: Можно стиль отрисовки границы выбрать отличным от стиля заливки самой стрелки? То есть, например, я хочу отрисовать стрелку одним цветом, а залить направляющий кончик другим?

Comment: @Дмитрий, я дополнил ответ. Прямого способа так сделать я не нашел, но можно попробовать подойти к проблеме творчески...

Comment: хорошо, спасибо!